# app crashes when cell is clicked and segueing to a different view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with a table view and a search bar. I'd like to send a user to one of the three other view controllers based on the text in the cell.

SearchViewController:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  
    if (searchBar.text == search[indexPath.row].cleanName) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "songs", sender: self)
    } else if (searchBar.text != search[indexPath.row].cleanName) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "artist", sender: self)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "albums", sender: self)
    }
    
}
```

Whenever I select the cell in the first view controller, my app crashes and I get **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SearchTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'** This error says that I must register a nib for my song view controller but I already did.

SearhesViewController:

```
  class SearchesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate  {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var searchesBar: UISearchBar!

var searchActive: Bool = false
var search = [Search]()
let filePath = "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles"
var songs = [Songs]()
var artists = [Artist]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "SearchTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchTableViewCell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchesBar.delegate = self
    retriveData()
    print(search)
}
     func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    songs = songs.filter({ (songName) -> Bool in
        return songName.songname.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil
        })

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if (searchActive) {
            return search.count
        } else {
            return 1
        }
      
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchTableViewCell", for:  indexPath) as! SearchTableViewCell
        
        cell.mainLabel!.text = search[indexPath.row].cleanName
        cell.secondLabel!.text = songs[indexPath.row].artistId
        cell.cellImage!.image = UIImage(named: songs[indexPath.row].cover)
        return cell;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let searchSong = search[indexPath.row].cleanName
        let searchArtist = search[indexPath.row].artistid
        let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(searchSong)\(searchArtist)"
        print(fileURLString)
        
    }
```

Comment: Please do not show snippets of code out of context and lumped together. Copy and paste _real_ code into the question, showing the _context_ in which the code appears. Your `tableView.register` call occurs _where?_ In what method of what class, exactly? Show enough of the the actual view controller declaration.

Comment: You likely forgot to register your nib, as the error suggests. Alternatively, your identifier name is not the same as it is in Interface Builder.

Comment: @matt Ok, the first snippet is where I started making changes and this crash popped up. The  `tableView.register` is in my viewDidLoad() of SearchesViewController and has a segue identifier of _songs_. Also the cell identifier is `SearchTableViewCell`

Comment: You are still not showing enough information. I would have to guess. For instance, maybe the `tableView` you are calling `register(nib:)` on is not the same as the `tableView` that you are trying to dequeue from. Impossible to tell without more code.

Comment: @matt I just added more code. I am also am using storyboard. My custom class for the cell is SearchTableViewCell and the identifier is SearchTableViewCell

Comment: Yup, I think that's enough to allow a decent answer. I think you are registering a nib that doesn't exist.

Comment: @matt I just don't understand why it would be crash for this because before I added the first snippet in SearchViewController the custom cell would work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no such nib. Therefore your call to

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "SearchTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
```

yields `nil`, and your call to

```
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchTableViewCell")
```

does nothing. You are saying the *words*, but you are not actually registering any nib. Hence the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cell is properly configured on a Storyboard:

1. Go to your cell on storyboard
2. In Identity Inspector, the cell must be set to **Custom Class**
   `SearchTableViewCell`

   [image]
3. In Attibutes Inspector, the cell **Identifier** must be set to `SearchTableViewCell`

   [image]